# Best options for - Spring XML parsing to read certain elements

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have read the spring documentation for reading/writing the XML documents..(http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html) 
The options provided using different typs of marshalling(Oxm, Jaxb, jibx, castor, xstream) all seems to be using the conversion of a document based on some mapping file or a java bean or identifying by comparing each individual element using xstream.

I have a requirement, where i will get big xml files and i need to read some of the elements only in it and i dont want to keep the complete xml into the memory.

What are the options that i have in spring?
if any of the options that the spring documentation provides and useful for my requirement, please provide some examples.

BTW, i am using latest spring 4... FYI.

Answer (score 2):

For large XML file you would need a SAX parser which is an event based parser.

Here an example
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Spring Object/XML Mapping is to convert XML to and from an object which is a different use case.